# Swift - How can I use a dictionary to give text for tableView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have the following JSON file:

```
[
{
"countryName": "Afghanistan",
"continent": "Asia",
"population": 34656032,
"currency": "Afghani"
},
{
"countryName": "Albania",
"continent": "Europe",
"population": 2876591,
"currency": "Lek"
},
{
"countryName": "Bulgaria",
"continent": "Europe",
"population": 7050034,
"currency": "Lev"
},
{
"countryName": "Finland",
"continent": "Europe",
"population": 5517887,
"currency": "Euro"
},
{
"countryName": "Iceland",
"continent": "Europe",
"population": 350710,
"currency": "Icelandic Krona"
},
{
"countryName": "Japan",
"continent": "Asia",
"population": 126672000,
"currency": "Yen"
},
{
"countryName": "Oman",
"continent": "Middle East",
"population": 4424762,
"currency": "Rial"
},
{
"countryName": "South Africa",
"continent": "Africa",
"population": 57725600,
"currency": "South African Rand"
},
{
"countryName": "Uruguay",
"continent": "South America",
"population": 3444006,
"currency": "Uruguayan Peso"
},
{
"countryName": "Venezuela",
"continent": "South America",
"population": 31568179,
"currency": "Bolivar Soberano"
}
]
```

After parsing it into my project using SwiftyJson, I'd like each cell in my tableView to have the title of the 'countryName', so have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var countries = [[String: String]]()
var numberOfCountries = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Select country"

    if let jsonPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Countries", ofType: "json") {

        if let data = try? String(contentsOfFile: jsonPath) {

            print("data: \(data)")

            let json = JSON(parseJSON: data)

            parse(json: json)

            print("countries: \(countries)")

        } else {
            print("Unable to get contents of JSON file")
        }
    }

}

func parse(json: JSON) {
    for result in json.arrayValue {
        let countryName = result["countryName"].stringValue
        let continent = result["continent"].stringValue
        let population = result["population"].stringValue
        let currency = result["currency"].stringValue

        let obj = ["countryName": countryName, "continent": continent, "population": population, "currency": currency]

        countries.append(obj)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberOfCountries = countries.count
    return numberOfCountries
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
    var cellTitle = ""

    for item in countries {
        cellTitle = item["countryName"] as! String
        print("cellTitle: \(cellTitle)")
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle
    return cell
}
```

However, the array is just looped-over ten different times, and Venezuela is selected as the title for every tableView cell.

My debug console comes up as follows:

```
countries: [["countryName": "Afghanistan", "continent": "Asia", "population": "34656032", "currency": "Afghani"], ["countryName": "Albania", "continent": "Europe", "population": "2876591", "currency": "Lek"], ["countryName": "Bulgaria", "continent": "Europe", "population": "7050034", "currency": "Lev"], ["countryName": "Finland", "continent": "Europe", "population": "5517887", "currency": "Euro"], ["countryName": "Iceland", "continent": "Europe", "population": "350710", "currency": "Icelandic Krona"], ["countryName": "Japan", "continent": "Asia", "population": "126672000", "currency": "Yen"], ["countryName": "Oman", "continent": "Middle East", "population": "4424762", "currency": "Rial"], ["countryName": "South Africa", "continent": "Africa", "population": "57725600", "currency": "South African Rand"], ["countryName": "Uruguay", "continent": "South America", "population": "3444006", "currency": "Uruguayan Peso"], ["countryName": "Venezuela", "continent": "South America", "population": "31568179", "currency": "Bolivar Soberano"]]
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
cellTitle: Afghanistan
cellTitle: Albania
cellTitle: Bulgaria
cellTitle: Finland
cellTitle: Iceland
cellTitle: Japan
cellTitle: Oman
cellTitle: South Africa
cellTitle: Uruguay
cellTitle: Venezuela
```

How could I loop over this array just one time, selecting the value of 'countryName' in each instance, then using that as my cell title?

Thanks to anyone who can help. This one's been driving me nuts!

Comment: Probabily your `parse()` method is getting called multiple times. Reset `countries` ie `countries. = []` while sending a parse request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looping over the entire array for each row

Instead of

```
var cellTitle = ""

for item in countries {
    cellTitle = item["countryName"] as! String
    print("cellTitle: \(cellTitle)")
}

cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle
```

Try

```
cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row]["countryName"] as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand how table views work.

`cellForRowAt` is called **once** for each row (number of `countries` times). You have to get the value in the data source array for the passed `indexPath` and update the UI:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
    let country = countries[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = country["countryName"]!
    return cell
}
```

---

The most efficient solution is to decode the JSON into structs with the `Codable` protocol (and throw away SwiftyJSON)

```
struct Country : Decodable {
    let countryName, continent, currency : String
    let population : Int
}

var countries = [Country]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Select country"

    // If the code crashes in one of the following lines you made a design mistake
    let jsonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Countries", withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: jsonURL)
    countries = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
    let country = countries[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = country.countryName
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called once for each cell the table view needs to create.

That means that in your implementation, you don't have to loop over your data, but rather return the one item that the table view is asking for right now. The parameter `indexPath` indicates which row you should return a cell for.

Since your data is a dictionary, a possible way to handle this would be storing its keys as an array and then use the property `indexPath.row` to access the key corresponding to the row.

Answer (score -1):

Well why do you loop through all of the items inside the cell for row at index path. The point there is to use the index path on the array as `countries[indexPath.row]["countryName"]`.

But there are some other things that might be a bit... Odd to use. Maybe start by studying the following refacture. I have removed mapping and used native tools to parse JSON just to make it more independent for now.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var countries: [[String: Any]]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Select country"
        reloadData()
    }

    private func reloadData() {
        if let jsonPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Countries", ofType: "json") {
            if let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: jsonPath) {

                if let stringRepresentation = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Data: \(stringRepresentation)")
                } else {
                    print("Could not represent data as string (\(data.count) bytes) ")
                }


                if let countries = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [[String: Any]] {
                    self.countries = countries
                    print("countries: \(countries)")
                } else {
                    print("Could not parse countries")
                }

            } else {
                print("Unable to get contents of JSON file")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let descriptor = self.countries?[indexPath.row] {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = descriptor["countryName"] as? String
            return cell
        } else {
            // No data!?
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

}
```

But as far as mapping goes it is nice at least to have your own structures. After it Swift has some nice tools like `compactMap` which will convert an array of 1 object type to another. See the following code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct Country {
        let name: String
        let continent: String?
        let population: Int
        let currency: String?

        init?(descriptor: [String: Any]) {
            guard let name = descriptor["countryName"] as? String else {
                return nil // We want at least the country name to be mandatory
            }
            self.name = name
            self.continent = descriptor["continent"] as? String
            self.population = (descriptor["population"] as? Int) ?? 0
            self.currency = descriptor["currency"] as? String
        }
    }

    private var countries: [Country]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Select country"
        reloadData()
    }

    private func reloadData() {
        if let jsonPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Countries", ofType: "json") {
            if let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: jsonPath) {

                if let stringRepresentation = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Data: \(stringRepresentation)")
                } else {
                    print("Could not represent data as string (\(data.count) bytes) ")
                }


                if let countries = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [[String: Any]] {
                    self.countries = countries.compactMap { Country(descriptor: $0) }
                    print("countries: \(countries)")
                } else {
                    print("Could not parse countries")
                }

            } else {
                print("Unable to get contents of JSON file")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let country = self.countries?[indexPath.row] {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = country.name
            return cell
        } else {
            // No data!?
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

}
```